# Lower bound on the probability of maximum of $n$ i.i.d. chi-square random variables exceeding a value close to their number of degrees of freedom

Tags: probability-theory, inequality, normal-distribution

I am wondering if there is a tight lower bound on the probability of a maximum of $n$ i.i.d. chi-square random variables, each with degree of freedom $d$ exceeding a value close to $d$.  Formally, I need to lower bound the following expression:

$$P(\max_i X_i\geq d+\delta)$$

where each $X_i\sim\chi^2_d$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ and $\delta$ is small.  Ideally, I would like an expression involving elementary functions of $n$, $d$, and $\delta$.  I am interested in the asymptotics and assume that $n$ and $d$ are large.

**What I tried**

We know that $P(\max_i X_i\geq d+\delta)=1-P(X<d+\delta)^n$ where $X\sim\chi^2_d$.  Therefore, I tried to upper bound $P(X<d+\delta)$ using the CLT, which yields the normal approximation to chi-squared distribution, and the lower bounds on the Q-function.  However, the resultant overall bound is not tight, and I am hoping something better exists.

Comment: Would it be possible to give any additional information regarding $d$? Is it large, does it help to work with even $d$, etc?

Comment: Both the number of degrees of freedom $d$ for each chi-square variate $X_i$ as well as their number $n$ is large.  However, I can't make assumptions on whether $d$ is even or not.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is helpful, but taking a look at what [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function) has to say about the cdf of the Chi-Square distribution, it appears that

\begin{align*}
   P[X < d+\delta]^n
&= \left( \left( \frac{d+\delta}{2}\right)^{d/2} e^{-d/2} 
   \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{d+\delta}{2}\right)^k}{\Gamma(d/2 + k + 1)}\right)^n \\
&= \left( e^{-d/2}  
   \sum_{y=d/2}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{d+\delta}{2}\right)^y}{\Gamma(y + 1)}\right)^n \\
&= e^{n\delta/2}\left(e^{-(d+\delta)/2}   
   \sum_{y=d/2}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{d+\delta}{2}\right)^y}{\Gamma(y + 1)}\right)^n,
\end{align*}
and so the term 
$$
 e^{-(d+\delta)/2}\sum_{y=d/2}^\infty \frac{\left(\frac{d+\delta}{2}\right)^y}{\Gamma(y + 1)}
$$
is bound above by $1$ (this is certainly clear for even $d$). It may be that the larger $d$ is, the further the term is from $1$.

Comment: Hmmm... thank you for your thoughts, but is there an arithmetic error in the third equation -- shouldn's the first exponential be $e^{n\delta/2}$, without the minus sign?  Otherwise the exponentials don't add up to $e^{-nd/2}$...

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry about the error. I have edited the post. I'm not so confident that this is helpful, but it was all I could think of at the time. I may ponder over it more if I get the chance. Good luck with this!